# Detect if app is opened from lock screen

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I'm creating an app that displays monitors iBeacon regions, which means that when the device is locked and within range of a beacon, my app's icon is shown on the lock screen in the bottom left.

Is there any way that I can detect if my app is launched through this lock screen icon, and run some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the icon appears, it indicates that a beacon region has been entered.  The `CLLocationManager` delegate's `didEnterRegion` method will be called when the icon first appears.

You can put custom code there to set a flag indicating the icon appeared.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    _iconShown = YES;
}
```

Then, when your app comes to the foreground, you can check this flag to see if it is set, and execute your custom logic:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    if (_iconShown) {
        _iconShown = NO;

        // Put custom logic here for launching from the icon
    }
}
```

Comment: Not perfect as the user could have launched the app on their own rather than from the lock screen, but this seems like a good compromise. I'll leave the question open for a bit longer to see if anything else comes through and if not I'll accept this as the answer, thanks!

Comment: It is true that this only tells you that the location event happened prior to the app being brought to the foreground by any means, but this is the best you can do.   This is a common problem.  The application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method gets access to launchOptions that can discern this, but this is only for the original launch and not returning to the foreground.  There is no equivalent of launchOptions for entering the foreground.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

hmm, there is an alternative way, that you can handle it, just create an variable `self.backgroundedToLockScreen` like:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    if (self.backgroundedToLockScreen) {
        ... // app was backgrounded to lock screen
    } else {
        ... // app was backgrounded on purpose by tapping the home button or switching apps.
    }
    self.backgroundedToLockScreen = NO;
}
```

and

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
    if (UIApplicationStateInactive == state ||  // detect if coming from locked screen (iOS 6)
        self.backgroundedToLockScreen)          // detect if backgrounded to the locked screen (iOS 7)
    {
        ... // app is coming from or was backgrounded to lock screen
    } else {
        ... // app was backgrounded on purpose by tapping the home button or switching apps
    }
    self.backgroundedToLockScreen = NO;
}
```

Hope this could be useful for you.

Comment: I don't really see how you are setting the backgroundedToLockScreen variable? When does it get set to YES? Either way, just because the user exits to the lock screen, doesn't mean that later they launched the app from the lock screen as well.